# How to execute other scripts such as bash and jython, from a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a script called **test.sh** which is located in the directory **/home/user** with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Execute command number 1 (bash)"
. /opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/control.sh
  
echo "Execute command number 2 (jython)"
. /opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy "@g"
```

---

When running command number 1 I get the following message:

```
./test.sh: line 5: /opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/control.sh: No such file or directory
```

When I go to the destination (/bin) and run the command from there, it has no issues.

---

When running command number 2 I get the following message:

```
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 1: Script: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 2: $'\E]0': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 2: $'user@XXXXX:~\a\E[?1034h[user@XXXXX': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 3: $'\E]0': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 3: user@XXXXX:/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/log/support[user@XXXXX: No such file or directory
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 4: total: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 5: -rw-r-----.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 5: $'31mTADDM_ISA_Collection.General.20220323140619.zip\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 6: $'\E]0': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 6: user@XXXXX:/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/log/support[user@XXXXX: No such file or directory
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 7: $'\E]0': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 7: user@XXXXX:/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/log/support[user@XXXXX: No such file or directory
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 8: total: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 9: $'\E]0': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 9: user@XXXXX:/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/log/support[user@XXXXX: No such file or directory
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 10: $'\E[3': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 10: $'J\E[H\E[2J\E]0': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 10: user@XXXXX:/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/log/support[user@XXXXX: No such file or directory
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 11: $'\E]0': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 11: $'user@XXXXX:~\a[user@XXXXX': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 12: total: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 13: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 13: $'34m12:35:27\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 14: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 14: $'34m2022\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 15: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 15: $'34m22\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 16: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 16: $'34mCET\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 17: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 17: $'34mMar\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 18: -rwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 18: $'32mmenu.sh\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 19: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 19: $'34mPM\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 20: $'\E]0': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 20: $'user@XXXXX:~\a[user@XXXXX': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 21: $'\E[3': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 21: $'J\E[H\E[2J\E]0': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 21: $'user@XXXXX:~\a[user@XXXXX': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 22: $'\E]0': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 22: $'user@XXXXX:~\a[user@XXXXX': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 23: total: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 24: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 24: $'34m12:35:27\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 25: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 25: $'34m2022\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 26: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 26: $'34m22\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 27: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 27: $'34mCET\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 28: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 28: $'34mMar\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 29: -rwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 29: $'32mmenu.sh\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 30: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 30: $'34mPM\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 31: -rw-rw-r--.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 32: $'\E]0': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 32: $'user@XXXXX:~\a[user@XXXXX': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 33: $'\E]0': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 33: $'user@XXXXX:~\a[user@XXXXX': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 34: total: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 35: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 35: $'34m12:35:27\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 36: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 36: $'34m2022\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 37: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 37: $'34m22\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 38: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 38: $'34mCET\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 39: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 39: $'34mMar\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 40: -rwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 40: $'32mmenu.sh\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 41: drwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 41: $'34mPM\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 42: -rwxrwxr-x.: command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 42: $'32mtest.sh\E[0m\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 43: $'\E]0': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 43: $'user@XXXXX:~\a[user@XXXXX': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 44: $'\E[3': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 44: $'J\E[H\E[2J\E]0': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 44: $'user@XXXXX:~\a[user@XXXXX': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 46: $'\r': command not found
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 51: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy: line 51: `do
```

When I go to the destination (/bin) and run the command from there, it has no issues.

---

I have also tried the commands without the file extensions (/bin/control & /bin/collect_logs) and I have tried to use `source` instead of `.` but that doesn't help either.

Why can I not run other scripts from within my own bash script?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to *source* them or *execute* them?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I want to execute them. I want to execute the commands from within a menu later on.

Comment: I'm confused. Is the script located at `/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/control.sh` or at `/bin/control.sh`. For the second command call, you cannot source a non-bash script, run it without `source` or `.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the scripts are in your $PATH and they are executable, means that you can start them from anywhere by typing
`control.sh` or `collect_logs.jy "@g"`

you can just do

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Execute command number 1 (bash)"
control.sh
  
echo "Execute command number 2 (jython)"
collect_logs.jy "@g"
```

If you need to specify the directory, just leave out the dot:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Execute command number 1 (bash)"
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/control.sh
  
echo "Execute command number 2 (jython)"
/opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy "@g"
```

you may need to make them executable first:

```
chmod +x /opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/control.sh
chmod +x /opt/IBM/taddm/dist/bin/collect_logs.jy
```